# Multiple dependent variables in ezAnova

Tags: anova

I am trying to generate an ezAnova table output, containing multiple dv's.

I found a 'similar' question here: ([Automatically performing multiple within-subject ANOVA in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646960/automatically-performing-multiple-within-subject-anova-in-r)), however this is creates a list which is not very handy to output as APA-style table.

Is there an easy way to specify multiple dv's within the formular?

I'm looking for something like this (which is not working obviously :) )

```
ezANOVA(
data=df
, dv= var1, var2
, wid = id
, between = iv
)
```